# How to consume a stream but still retain the data without offsetting

Tags: stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, retain

we have a need to retain the data in the stream after the first transaction consumes it. How do we do this? The second transaction will consume again and offset the stream. Need a solution for the 2nd DML to see the stream data after the first DML is done. both the DML's will need the same data in the stream.

Comment: Using explicit transaction with BEGIN, DML1, DML2, COMMIT.

Answer (score 3):

Sergiu's comment would be the much preferred option but another approach may be to query the stream first using a simple SELECT statement and then follow it up with a DML statement based on the last query result

```
SELECT * FROM my_stream;


INSERT INTO my_table select * from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach and allows use of the results for 24 hours, which opens up possibilities for post processing and replays.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended that users create a separate stream for each change record recipient for the table.

Note that a stream itself does not contain any table data.

Reference: [Multiple Consumers of Streams](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html#multiple-consumers-of-streams)